# Sieve of Eratosthenes with a Swing UI

Tags: java, beginner, csv, swing, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm fairly new to Java. I want to divide my code into 3 classes. First class to contain my GUI, second to compute the algorithm and third class to write results in my file. I have the code working but I can't get to divide it in 3 separate classes. All i want to know is by example, how can i make parameter `list` that I calculate in `Computer` class to work in `Writer` class and so on. I wrote my full code , and then the attempts to divide it.

#### Full code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PrimeNumbers {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;


    public static void main(String[] args) {



        PrimeNumbers window = new PrimeNumbers();
        window.frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public PrimeNumbers() {
        initialize();
    }


    public  List<Integer> Calculate() throws IOException {
        String getTxt = textField.getText();
        Integer x = Integer.parseInt(getTxt);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        boolean [] isComposite = new boolean [x + 1];
        isComposite[1] = true;


        for (int i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
            if (!isComposite[i]) {

                list.add(i);
                int multiple = 2;
                while (i * multiple <= x) {
                    isComposite [i * multiple] = true;
                    multiple++;
                }
            }
        }
        File file = new File("C:/Users/TudorV/Desktop/File.csv");


        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(String.valueOf(list));
        bw.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, list);
        return list;
    }



    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textField = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnGetPrimeNumbers = new JButton("Get prime numbers");
        btnGetPrimeNumbers.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    Calculate();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnGetPrimeNumbers, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

}
```

### Attempts

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by TudorV on 30/06/2016.
 */
public class Writer extends Computer {



    public void writer(int list) throws IOException {


        File file = new File("C:/Users/TudorV/Desktop/File.csv");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(String.valueOf(list));
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by TudorV on 30/06/2016.
 */
public class Computer{
    public List<Integer> Calculate(int x) throws IOException {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        boolean [] isComposite = new boolean [x + 1];
        isComposite[1] = true;


        for (int i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
            if (!isComposite[i]) {

                list.add(i);
                int multiple = 2;
                while (i * multiple <= x) {
                    isComposite [i * multiple] = true;
                    multiple++;
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PrimeNumbers extends Writer{

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Writer one = new Writer();
        Computer two = new Computer();
        PrimeNumbers three = new PrimeNumbers();
        three.frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public PrimeNumbers() {
        initialize();
    }


    public  List<Integer> Calculate() throws IOException {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        boolean [] isComposite = new boolean [x + 1];
        isComposite[1] = true;


        for (int i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
            if (!isComposite[i]) {

                list.add(i);
                int multiple = 2;
                while (i * multiple <= x) {
                    isComposite [i * multiple] = true;
                    multiple++;
                }
            }
        }
        File file = new File("C:/Users/TudorV/Desktop/File.csv");


        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(String.valueOf(list));
        bw.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, list);
        return list;
    }



    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textField = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnGetPrimeNumbers = new JButton("Get prime numbers");
        btnGetPrimeNumbers.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    Calculate();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnGetPrimeNumbers, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I started by moving the `main` method into a `Main` class.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        display.start(new Calculator(), new Writer("C:/Users/TudorV/Desktop/File.csv"));
    }

}
```

This uses classes for `Display`, `Calculator`, and `Writer`.  I renamed `initialize` to `start` because I changed the usage somewhat.

I moved the file name into this method so that it is easy to find and change.  In a more serious program you might make it an argument (`args`) or add it to the form in `Display`.

`Display` is mostly similar to your original `PrimeNumbers` class.

```
public class Display {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField();

    public void start(Calculator calculator, Writer writer) {
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnGetPrimeNumbers = new JButton("Get prime numbers");
        btnGetPrimeNumbers.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String getTxt = textField.getText();
                int x = Integer.parseInt(getTxt);
                List<Integer> list = calculator.calculate(x);

                writer.write(list);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, list);
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(btnGetPrimeNumbers, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

However, I moved the calculations and file writing out of this class.  I pass in objects to handle those responsibilities.  They get called by the `ActionListener` on the button as you did originally.

Skipping down to `Writer`

```
public class Writer {

    String fileName;

    public Writer(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public void write(List<Integer> list) {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile()))) {
            bw.write(String.valueOf(list));
        }
    }

}
```

I added a new field (`fileName`) and set it in the constructor.

If you're just printing the stack trace, there isn't much point in catching the exception.  That's the default behavior anyway.

I changed the code to use [`try`-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).  This ensures that the `BufferedWriter` gets closed even if there is an exception.

Going back to `Calculator`

```
public class Calculator {

    public List<Integer> calculate(int ceiling) {
        boolean [] composites = new boolean[ceiling + 1];

        List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 2; i <= 3 && i <= ceiling; i++) {
            primes.add(i);
        }

        int increment = 4;
        for (int i = 5; i < composites.length; i += increment) {
            if (!composites[i]) {
                primes.add(i);
                for (int j = i * i; j < composites.length; j += i) {
                    composites[j] = true;
                }
            }

            increment = 6 - increment;
        }

        return primes;
    }

}
```

As you may have noticed, I made a few changes.

I made `calculate` lower case, as that is the standard for single word Java method naming (a special instance of camelCase).

I changed `x` to `ceiling` as a more descriptive name.  And `list` to `primes` for the same reason.  I changed `isComposite` to `composites` because variables should have noun names.

Rather than check every number, I skip all the even numbers and odd numbers divisible by three.  It's easy to skip evens by adding 2 instead of just incrementing by 1.  To skip the numbers divisible by three, we alternate incrementing by 2 and 4.  This produces 5, 7, skip 9 (because we increment 7 by 4), 11, 13, skip 15, 17, 19, skip 21...

That requires special logic to handle 2 and 3.

I changed the actual sieving code from a `while` loop to a `for` loop.

You start with a multiple of 2 and multiply each iteration.  I started with the square.  Realize that you already marked the smaller multiples as composites.  No need to do it again.  Similarly, if we increment by the number rather than 1, we can make `j` the actual number that needs marked.  That saves a multiplication each iteration.

Note:  I didn't look much at your Attempts code.  It didn't follow the approach that I would take.  In particular, I saw no reason to use `extends` to relate those classes.  When you use inheritance, it should generally be because one class is a special instance of another.  But even then, you often should [prefer composition (including fields of the relevant type) to inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002).

Comment: Thank you for the awesome explanation of the code, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

I would go further on responsibilities. I would introduce a listener pattern. So the Main-class looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Display display = new Display();
    Writer writer = new Writer("C:/Users/TudorV/Desktop/File.csv");

    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

    calculator.addListener(display);
    calculator.addListener(writer);

    calculator.calculate(1000);

}
```

The idea is to have every class that writes or displays the result depending on the model class "Calculator" because this class is producing the result. Why should Writer depend on Display or vice versa?

The Listener-interface should look like this:

```
public interface CalculatorListener {

    void onCalculationFinished(List<Integer> primes);

}
```

Implemented by "Display":

```
public class Display implements CalculatorListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCalculationFinished(List<Integer> primes) {

        ...

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, primes);

        ...

    }

    ...

}
```

And implemented by "Writer":

```
public class Writer implements CalculatorListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCalculationFinished(List<Integer> primes) {

        ...

        write(primes);

        ...

    }

    ...

}
```

The Calculator will not return a list anymore (this would be my design decision, but it is only an option) but notify the registered listeners after finishing its calculation:

```
public class Calculator {

    private Set<CalculatorListener> listeners;

    public Calculator() {
        this.listeners = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void calculate(int ceiling) {
        boolean [] composites = new boolean[ceiling + 1];

        List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

        ...

        notifyOnCalculationFinished(primes);
    }

    private void notifyOnCalculationFinished(List<Integer> primes) {
        for (CalculatorListener calculatorListener : listeners) {
            calculatorListener.onCalculationFinished(primes);
        }
    }

    public void addListener(CalculatorListener listener) {
        this.listeners.add(listener);
    }

}
```

The [listener pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) adresses the [dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) as the Calculator can communicate with subclasses of the Listener-contract "CalculatorListener" without knowing the concrete implementation.

Also we adress the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) when we unburden the UI class "Display" of "writing" something.